# bash commands to remote hosts - errors with writing local output files

Tags: bash, file, unix, ssh, remote-server

I'm trying to run several sets of commands in parallel on a few remote hosts.
I've created a script that constructs these commands, and then writes the output in a local file, something along the lines of:

```
ssh <me>@<ip1> "command" 2> ./path/to/file/newFile1.txt & ssh <me>@<ip2> 
"command" 2> ./path/to/file/newFile2.txt & ssh <me>@<ip2> "command" 2> 
./path/to/file/newFile3.txt; ...(same repeats itself, with new commands and new 
file names)...
```

My issue is that, when my script runs these commands, I am getting the following errors:

```
bash:  ./path/to/file/newFile1.txt: No such file or directory
bash:  ./path/to/file/newFile2.txt: No such file or directory
bash:  ./path/to/file/newFile3.txt: No such file or directory
...
```

These files do NOT exist but will be written. That being said, the directory paths are valid.

The strange thing is that, if I copy and paste the whole big command, then it works without any issue. I'd rather have it automated tho ;).

Any ideas?

**Edit - more information:**

My filesystem is the following:

```
- home
  - User
    - Desktop
      - Servers
        - Outputs
          - ...
```

I am running the bash script from home/User/Desktop/Servers.
The script creates the commands that need to be run on the remote servers. First thing first, the script creates the directories where the files will be stored.

```
outputFolder="./Outputs"
...
mkdir -p ${outputFolder}/f{fileNumb}
...
```

The script then continues to create the commands that will be called on remotes hosts, and their respective outputs will be placed in the created directories. 
The directories are there. Running the commands gives me the errors, however printing and then copying the commands into the same location works for some reason. I have also tried to give the full path to directory, still same issue.

Hope I've been a bit clearer.

Comment: The path has to exist for the redirection to work (the intermediate directories aren't automagically created). So `mkdir -p path/to/file` before the redirection `> path/to/file/newFile.txt`.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to contain enough of the relevant information to allow anything other than speculation. Please produce a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem, so that all of the relevant information (and minimal irrelevant info) is here.

Comment: Your question *still* doesn't contain enough information to actually tell what's happening -- that's the point of creating an MCVE. But your mention of "creating commands" makes me suspicious -- are you trying to store commands in variables before executing them? If so, there are many things that can go wrong. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: I just realized my mistake was not calling "eval" on the variable which contained my command string. Should have given the full script from the start, you're right. Will make sure my next questions contain a MCVE.

Comment: @dtam `eval` is almost never the right answer in shell scripting. It's really easy to write scripts that work perfectly when you test them, but then in general use some unexpected metacharacter shows up in some data, changes how everything gets parsed, and suddenly things you thought were just data are trying to execute as commands... Basically, it's a huge footgun. There's almost always a better way to do it. BashFAQ #50 has some good suggestions, but if none of them work in your situation I'd recommend asking about the best way to do it (as a new question).

Answer (score 1):

If this is the exact error message you get:

```
bash:  ./path/to/file/newFile1.txt: No such file or directory
```

Then you'll note that there's an extra space between the colon and the dot, so it's actually trying to open a file called `" ./path/to/file/newFile1.txt"` (without the quotes).

However, to accomplish that, you'd need to use quotes around the filename in the redirection, as in

```
something ... 2> " ./path/to/file/newFile1.txt"
```

Or the first character would have to something else than a regular space. A non-breaking space perhaps, possible something that some editor might create if you hit alt-space or such.

Comment: Was a good idea, but I've checked again and there is a single space.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you've shown enough to correctly answer the question.

This doesn't look like a problem with ssh, but the way you are calling the (`ssh`) commands.

You say that you are writing the commands into a file... presumably you are then running that file as a script.  Could you show the code you use to do that.  I believe that's your problem.

I suspect you have made a false assumption about the way the working directory changes when you run a script.  It doesn't.  You are listing relative paths, so its important to know what they are relative to.  That is the most likely reason for it working when you copy and paste it... You are executing from a different working directory.

Comment: When I copy and paste it, I do so in the same location as the script I am running. I've edited my original post with some more information, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to bash scripting and was building my script based on another one I had seen. I was "running" the command by simply calling the variable where the command was stored:

```
$cmd
```

Solved by using:

```
eval $cmd
```

instead. My bad, should have given the full script from the start.